# Getting rid of Status Bar on 4.1

Tags: android

I need to get rid of the system bar on Android 4.1 tablets since the tablets will be in a commercial/retail environment and be used for business. My app will be the only app used on the tablet and it needs as much screen real estate as possible for what we're trying to do. I have searched already and I see that there are ways to do it on a rooted tablet, however since this will be in a business and deployed to several hundred or thousand businesses, I cannot have all the tablets rooted for legal and security issues. (Would I really have issues legally though if I were to root them?)

I know that you can dim the status bar and make the buttons dots but that really isn't optimal.

If there is no way to get rid of it, is it possible to change the status bar icons and functionality? I ask this because our app has a status bar on top and we could possibly move it to the bottom and change the icons and functionality of the status bar to match the app's status bar so no screen real estate is lost.

I have read that 4.2 adds some fullscreen functionality for apps. Is this true? Can the status bar be hidden in 4.2 as opposed to 4.1?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to get rid of the system bar on Android 4.1 tablets

That is not possible, except via rooted devices and/or ROM mods. Moreover, the user needs this bar to be there, otherwise they have no access to the HOME and BACK buttons.

> Would I really have issues legally though if I were to root them?

StackOverflow is not a law office. Please consult with qualified legal counsel regarding such concerns.

> is it possible to change the status bar icons and functionality?

That is not possible, except via rooted devices and/or ROM mods.

> I have read that 4.2 adds some fullscreen functionality for apps. Is this true?

Not exactly. The bottom navigation bar (HOME, BACK, RECENTS) can be hidden, but they will return as soon as the user touches the screen. The top status bar (signal strength, battery level, etc.) can be removed via a `Fullscreen` theme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would I be able to recompile Android with this functionality included? Would this require me to keep it rooted?